# create a user control Treeview in metro

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

There's no treeview control in win rt, anyone know how to create a treeview user control? Any control should I inheritant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation by hierarchical structure is better visualize with ListView in winrt. You need to display a list of nodes, when user touches a node, it should display ListView with sub nodes and button back.

But you can implement own control TreeView (that looks like WPF or Silverlight TreeView). You need to derive from ListBox and ListBoxItem controls, and add indent for subnodes at PrepareContainerForItemOverride() method.